# Microsoft Partner Center usb driver cab file submission issues

Tags: driver, microsoft-partnercenter-java

In order to authenticate the usb driver that was used, I attempted to submit hardware to the Microsoft Partner Center.
However, the cause of the error is not indicated and only the phrase "Error" is displayed.

I made the cab file as the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/code-signing-attestation

```
.OPTION EXPLICIT 
.Set CabinetFileCountThreshold=0 
.Set FolderFileCountThreshold=0 
.Set FolderSizeThreshold=0 
.Set MaxCabinetSize=0 
.Set MaxDiskFileCount=0 
.Set MaxDiskSize=0 
.Set CompressionType=MSZIP 
.Set Cabinet=on 
.Set Compress=on 
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=USB_DRIVER_x64.cab 
.Set DestinationDir=USB_DRIVER_x64
D:\USB\DRIVER_x64.inf
D:\USB\DRIVER_x64.sys
D:\USB\DRIVER_x64.pdb
D:\USB\DRIVER_x64.cat
```

The .inf, .sys, .pdb, and .cat files were all included, and the .cat and .pdb files were excluded, but the results were the same.